# Is there anywhere in the London area to experience an American-style Thanksgiving Dinner?

Tags: london, public-holidays

I'll be in London over Thanksgiving this year.  I'd rather not completely miss out on the American holiday, if I can help it.  Is there anywhere in London where this holiday can be celebrated?  Perhaps a church or U.S. expat group which has a traditional Thanksgiving meal?

When in Mexico, English-speaking churches often hosted Thanksgiving meals, but the English-speaking church goers in England are naturally quite a different crowd, without such a high concentration of Americans, so I'm not really sure where to look.

Comment: Maybe look for an expat forum for Americans in the UK. Facebook might have one.

Comment: Or the embassy will have something for sure :)

Comment: @Ansari: I checked the embassy web site, and it has a nice explanation of the Thanksgiving holiday, but I didn't find any mention of where to celebrate it. I imagine if I were to call them, they might help me, but I'm not sure I'm that ambitious :)

Comment: An American ex-pat living in London that you know at all will likely invite a homesick American over for Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several restaurants offer Thanksgiving Dinners, with prices ranging from roughly £20 to £130.  Some can be found with brief descriptions at the links below.

- [Timeout London: Thanksgiving Meals in London](http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/thanksgiving-meals-in-london)
- [About.com UK Travel: Where to Celebrate Thanksgiving in London](http://gouk.about.com/od/festivalsandevents/a/ThanksgivingUK.htm)
- [METRO: Top 10 places in London to find Thanksgiving dinner](http://metro.co.uk/2012/11/22/top-10-places-in-london-to-find-thanksgiving-dinner-539646/)